# Inotify not recognizing new files in directory

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

I'm trying to use Inotify to monitor files being copied to a directory. The program appears to be functional, and will notify me when I enter the directory and run `ls`, for example (see below). However, it doesn't seem to catch new files that are being copied in.

Unsure if this is relevant, but the files are being copied in by another user. I'm running Inotify on a computing cluster. As far as I can tell I have full read/write/execute permission in the directory.

This is the command I've used directly in terminal:

`~/Modules/inofity-tools/3.14/bin/inotifywait -m /proj/cryoemcore/INCOMING/20200728_RM_NW/Data/`

Output is as follows:

```
Watches established.
/proj/cryoemcore/INCOMING/20200728_RM_NW/Data/ OPEN,ISDIR 
/proj/cryoemcore/INCOMING/20200728_RM_NW/Data/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Newly created files and files moved to the directory get reported.

Comment: I cannot reproduce as well. You don't get any types of events *at all* after copying files into the watched directory?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well. In my case, the machine writing data (files) into the folder is different than the machine that is watching. I'm unsure if this is related. I believe one machine is mounting the folder using SAMBA and the other using VirioFS. I imagine this is more likely the culprit. Still investigating